# Create Lambda Trigger from Kinesis Stream in serverless.yml file

Tags: serverless-framework

I am trying to create a lambda triggered aws via my serverless.yml file  I am able to create both the Kinesis stream and attach it to the lambda via the yml process no problem, but I am not able to do both at once, in what appears to be a race condition.

I am creating the Kinesis strea via the resources function (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/):

```
resources:  // CloudFormation template syntax
    Resources:
        streamName:
            Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
            Properties:
                Name: kinesis-stream
                ShardCount: 1
```

And I can attach a Lambda this way: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/streams/

However, when I do both of these, the Lambda appears to encounter a race condition deploying, and I have to re-enable manually the kinesis trigger on the lambda.  This appears to be because these both get created in parallel, and the stream doesn't exist when the Lambda has it added as it's trigger.

Is there a workaround/best practice for this?  Is the only solution to create the stream before deploying my serverless elements?

Comment: Have you tried using the `DependsOn` attribute available to CloudFormation resources?

Comment: Can I use this in the event though?  The Lambda depends on the Kinesis stream not the other way around.

Comment: Oh. Hmm from what I gather from this related GitHub issue (https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/68) the workaround is to create a separate infrastructure stack that gets deployed first, and your stack will refer to it. :/

Comment: This worked Trent, thanks.